# add column barcode(EAN) in invoice

Tags: invoice, custom, pdf

i would like add a colum in my invoice PDF.

so I changed the "draw ()" function found in the "app / code / core / Mage / Sales / Model / Order / Pdf / Items / Invoice" file by adding "item-> getEan ()

but i dont'woks.What method should I use to get the "EAN"?

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume EAN is an attribute you added to your product. The `$item` you're referring to is actually an invoice item and not a product so it doesn't have all the attributes available that a product would, it only has the things it needs for the invoice structure.

You can try doing the following:

```
$item->getProduct()->getEan()
```

I however suspect that wont work and you'll want to use:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
     ->getAttributeRawValue( $item->getProductId() , 'ean', $order->getStoreId());
```

Using that you should be able to add the EAN to the `draw()` method in the invoice class. Be aware that you will need to adjust the table header as well and add the EAN in there somewhere.